# Grails Elasticsearch plugin creates index on startup? How do I stop it?

Tags: grails, elasticsearch

I need to put a new ES index in place to switch over to at some point in the future. I've been using aliases to do this, by having my app reference an alias, and using the HTTP API to point the alias at either the existing or new index as needed. Unfortunately, when the app gets re-started it complains that the index already exists as an alias. See stacktrace:

```
org.elasticsearch.indices.InvalidIndexNameException: [redacted] Invalid index name [redacted], already exists as alias
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService.validateIndexName(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:174)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService.validate(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:510)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService.access$100(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:86)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$2.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:209)
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:328)
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
```

Anyone got any idea why this is happening  and how I can prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been fixed, coincidentally, by the release of v0.0.4.0 the plugin today

https://noamt.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/guide/single.html#history